# Class WSMessage not found in

Tags: php

I try to run SOAP client in PHP to call rampart axis2/java.

```
  // Create message with request payload and options
$reqMessage = new WSMessage($reqPayloadString,
                     array("to" => "http://localhost:9090/axis2/services/SecureService",
                           "action" => "http://php.rampart.apache.org"));
```

But there is an error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'WSMessage' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\rampart.php on line 21
```

I added wsf.dll to php/ext/ and config php.ini extension to use wsf.dll

I using xampp v1.7.5 (php5.3.3) and copy wsf.dll from wso2-wsf-php-bin-1.0.0-win32

Please help me solve the problem.

Thank you.